# XSS - encode - decode a href/url

Tags: java, jsp, xss, aem

I have a usecase where I have a text input field which takes URL and saves it.
That saved url is used in a jsp file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var defaultSimulatorUrl = '<%= defaultSimulatorUrl %>';
</script>
```

Variable defaultSimulatorUrl is used to show in prefilled text input fields

Some attacker can attack defaultSimulatorUrl's value by sending **http://abcxyz.com?a=b&c=d';alert(1);//**

Script content will be converted to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var defaultSimulatorUrl = 'http://abcxyz.com?a=b&c=d';alert(1);//';
</script>
```

My problem is if I encode this Url using **com.adobe.granite.xss.XSSAPI.encodeForHTML()**, how can i get orignal url to show in input field

Or Can I encode it by some other means to be used in prefilled text input fields

XSSAPI does not provides api to decode string back

Comment: your code example shows JavaScript where you need to encode it, but your question is about an input field. You shouldn't need to use the XSSAPI there...

Comment: I don't know much about jsp, but I guess If you pass jsp varibale in side JavaScript, then you can sanitize it in jsp before passing it to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used XSSAPI's encodeForJS method which solved my problem